# How can I migrate data from one HDFS cluster to another over the network?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

What options do I have for reliably migrating data from one (small) HDFS cluster to another completely separate installation?

I have a network connection between clusters (this question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276313/transferring-whole-hdfs-from-one-cluster-to-another))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using distcp command which is available in Hadoop.

Check the below link to know about more

[DistCp](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_7_2.html)

**Example**

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/a hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/b
```

Comment: can you please state with syntax or example ?